# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name java:comp is not bound in this Context

Tags: spring

I am trying to build a war using the following:

- Spring Framework 3.0.6
- JSF 2.1.6
- ICEfaces 3.1

the configuration file for spring is in the /conf/rb_conf.xml.

```
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/conf/rb_conf.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name java:comp is not bound in this Context
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:563)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1399)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1500)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:252)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:194)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:600)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1703)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name java:comp is not bound in this Context
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
...
```

I have been trying to solve this issue but with no luck, can anyone help?
Any Ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error is ocurring during the access of some JNDI resource which the name starts with "java:comp", and this resource does not exist in the server. Are you using a datasource configured in the server? What server are you using?

Comment: Hi I am using apache-tomcat-6.0.36. And yes I am using a datasource configured in the GlobalNamingResources. The name of the resources is: mysqlPool

Comment: Please, post the GlobalNamingResources fragment and the spring configuration file.

Comment: <Resource name="mysqlPool" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
   username="username" password="*****" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp" validationQuery="" maxActive="20"
   maxIdle="2" maxWait="5000" />

Comment: <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/mysqlPool" />
 </bean>

Comment: Have you referenced the global resource in the tomcat context.xml, like this:

  <ResourceLink name="mysqlPool"
   global="mysqlPool"
   type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>